# vim scripting: how to make a variable to host command

Tags: vim

I have the following code to copy the file I am editing to another folder, but when execute the command by press `F5`, it tries to do command `"copy path newpath"` literally without replace the variables with the their value. What's the solution?

```
function! Cpf()

let path = expand('%:p')
echo path
echo "123"
let newpath = substitute(path,'test1','test2','g')
echo "copy " path newpath
:!copy path newpath
endfunction

:map <F5> :call Cpf()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the line:

```
:!copy path newpath
```

into

```
call system("copy ".path." ".newpath)
```

or this

```
exec '!copy ' . path . ' ' . newpath
```

Note that if you used `copy`, it means, it won't work for almost all *nix systems. You may want to add a OS check if you want it to be portable.

Comment: Thanks Kent, it works. But could you please point me to some doc? What's the meaning of .path." ".newpath,  does the dot concat the string?

Comment: the "dot" concatenates the string to build your external command. for help, `:h system(` and `:h :exec` @DanielWu